# Original English track of "The Gods must be crazy"?

Tags: alternate-version, comedy

Althought from South Africa, the movie "The Gods Must Be Crazy" had been shot directly in English (apart for the bushmen who speak their native langage). However, some actors had such a strong SA accent that they have eventually been dubbed (still in English) for the theatrical release. I have checked on several international DVD editions from different countries, and it seems that the dubbed version is the only one available.

My question: does the "original", non-dubbed, English version exist around? Has it been been released at some point, or was the theatrical release in SA also the dubbed version? The dubbed version can easily be identified, because the audio processing is completely different between the dubbed and non-dubbed actors (and this is strinking in the dialogues that mix both).